# jQuery: hiding table row in IE 8 closes the browser?

Tags: jquery

So, I am looking at the piece of code:

```
var row = $(deletebutton).parent().parent();
            var indexLabel = $(row).find("#" + indexLableId);
            var rowIndex = $(indexLabel).val();

            $(row).remove();
```

If I change last line to

```
 $(row).hide();
```

the IE8 closes. What gives?

Update: This is very interesting now. If I click on the first row only IE crashes, on any other row it switches to compatibility view. It happens even if I do this

```
row[0].style.display = "none";
```

so it is not jQuery problem at all. Code is not mine nor the screen so I'll have to take a look what is going on.

Update 2: Ok, I think I know what is going on. Whoever coded this crap used same ids for children element in each row.

Comment: Does this help at all - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567398/jquery-ie-crashing-on-somediv-hide

Answer (score 0):

where is deletebutton set, what's in it?

i don' think you need the $() around row b/c .parent will return a jQuery object already.

try just `row.hide();`